# Vertical Spacing in \frac

Tags: math-mode, spacing, fractions

So I am using `\frac` and it looks like the content in my denominator is touching the line, is there any way I can use a simple `\vspace` to correct the issue? Is there an easy fix or do I have to mess around with something else?

I'm using:

```
$= \frac{P(A \ \cap \ B)}{P(B)}$
```

*sorry, couldn't get the  [Google Chart API](https://developers.google.com/chart/) to show what I wanted*

This is what I was thinking:

```
$= \frac{P(A \ \cap \ B)}{\vspace{1mm} P(B)}$
```

This is being called in an `article` class, inside an `\enumerate` and `\item`.

**Edit:** So after trying some of the suggestions in the comments I found that using `\displaystyle` prior to `\frac` made the text match the default font size  rather than the whole fraction matching the font size like in just using `\frac`.

*The differences don't show in [Google Chart API](https://developers.google.com/chart/). (At least it didn't seem to be any different for me)*

I liked using `\vphantom{}` as an exponent to create an invisible character, when just using `\frac` it actually fixed the issue with the denominator touching the line. Pretty clever.

**Edit2:** `\dfrac` is  simpler alternative to `\displaystyle\frac` but it requires the `amsmath` package. `\mfrac` is a nice in-between the display and regular styles and it requires the `nccmath`.

Comment: The problem is because now it is inline equation. So you can change this to `$\displaystyle\frac{P(A \ \cap \ B)}{P(B)}$` (the size will be bigger) or `$\frac{P(A \ \cap \ B)}{P(B)^{\vphantom{X}}}$` as an easy fix.

Comment: Use \vphantom{} with something tall inside the curlies.

Comment: \mathstrut is generally big enough (no \phantom required)  \rule{0pt}{?ex} is adjustable.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  Instead of describing the use case, it would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: Use `\dfrac` in that case?

Comment: Or the intermediate `\mfrac` from `nccmath`?